# Configure nextcloud-fpm docker-compose with bare metal nginx

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose, fpm

I'm trying to install Nextcloud on my server.
The nginx service is installed directly on bare metal (Ubuntu)

I starting from the docker-compose found at  https://github.com/nextcloud/docker/tree/master/.examples/docker-compose/with-nginx-proxy/postgres/fpm

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  postgres-nextcloud:
    image: postgres:alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5435:5432
    volumes:
      - postgres-nextcloud-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
      - db.env

  redis-nextcloud:
    image: redis:alpine
    restart: always

  nextcloud:
    image: nextcloud:fpm-alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8083:9000
    volumes:
      - /var/www/cloud.domain.com:/var/www/html
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_HOST=postgres-nextcloud
      - REDIS_HOST=redis-nextcloud
      - POSTGRES_PORT=5432
    env_file:
      - db.env
    depends_on:
      - postgres-nextcloud
      - redis-nextcloud

  web:
    build: ./web
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /var/www/cloud.domain.com:/var/www/html:ro
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=cloud.domain.com
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=cloud.domain.com
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=dev@domain.com
    depends_on:
      - nextcloud
    networks:
      - proxy-tier
      - default

  cron:
    image: nextcloud:fpm-alpine
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /var/www/cloud.domain.com:/var/www/html
    entrypoint: /cron.sh
    depends_on:
      - postgres-nextcloud
      - redis-nextcloud
```

But with my knowledge in web server I haven't found the way to properly configure my "local" nginx.

I've many other website, app already working using this nginx instance
All the different config are in the sites-available directory
The config for the Nextcloud project is named cloud.mydomain.com

with this nginx config I only get a File not found. Page

```
server {
  root /var/www/cloud.domain.com;
  server_name cloud.domain.com www.cloud.domain.com;

  index index.html index.htm index.php;

  charset utf-8;

  location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
      gzip_static on;
  }

  location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
  location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

  error_page 404 /index.php;

  location ~ \.php$ {
      try_files $uri =404;
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_pass localhost:8083;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
  }

  error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

  listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
  listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/cloud.domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/cloud.domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
  if ($host = www.cloud.domain.com) {
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  } # managed by Certbot


  if ($host = cloud.domain.com) {
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  } # managed by Certbot

  server_name cloud.domain.com www.cloud.domain.com;

  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

I understand that -fpm app need a proxy but I don't really understand how to link it to my existing nginx set up. With the nginx NOT running in a docker container.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

One way I know is to install another nginx in another container and put those two containers in one network in docker...

Use your baremetal nginx as reverse proxy then forward traffic to the nginx in container will do the trick.

The other way is to use the image nextcloud:latest  which comes with built in Apache server. Its actually the first way with built-in web server.

I heard there some way to configure your docker image to behave like a service installed on baremetal (with own public IP) by setting the network-mode in docker-compose files but I think its easier to just include another nginx server in docker...

Either way your existing service on baremetal will not be affected.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).